# How can I remove memtest from boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I first installed Windows 8 and then Ubuntu. There was no Windows entry on the boot screen, so I did grub-update and now it is present, but I also have 2 additional memtest entries in the list.
Is there a way to remove those from the list and have only Windows and Ubuntu there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's just the `memtest` options you don't want, you can simply remove that package:

```
sudo apt-get remove memtest86+
```

You can also control the generation of the submenus (the "Advanced options for ..." entries), and the recovery options by editing `/etc/default/grub`. From the grub info documentation:

```
'GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY'
     If this option is set to 'true', disable the generation of recovery
     mode menu entries.
```

and

```
'GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU'
     Normally, 'grub-mkconfig' will generate top level menu entry for
     the kernel with highest version number and put all other found
     kernels or alternative menu entries for recovery mode in submenu.
     For entries returned by 'os-prober' first entry will be put on top
     level and all others in submenu.  If this option is set to 'y',
     flat menu with all entries on top level will be generated instead.
```

For more details on the grub configuration, check out:

```
 info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```

Comment: So those were added from ubuntu? I thought it was some bios thing I wasn't supposed to mess with.

Comment: Nope, those are provided by Ubuntu.

Comment: Any way I can remove the 'ubuntu advanced options boot', too?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: sure, I've added info in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know the post is old, but it still comes up in  searches.

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
sudo update-grub
```

This will hide it from grub by setting execution bit to off. Enable it back by replacing "-" with "+".

Answer (score -2):

You can edit list in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Also, please do the backup first. ;)

Comment: As it says at the top of that file (`DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
`), the changes will be lost next time `update-grub` is run (typically, when the next kernel update is installed).

Comment: I know about notes in the top of file. Just comment memtest  in the ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ### conf block.