# Getting memory test option alongside Ubuntu and Windows 10 boot options

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, ram

Was facing issue(hardware) with grub when uninstalled Ubuntu 16.04 which was installed along with Windows 10 later replaced the hard disk. When tried to install Windows 10 it was showing error of "File :- \EFI\microsoft\boot\bcd" "Info :- The Boot Configuration Data for your pc is missing or contains errors".

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \EFI\microsoft\boot\bcd  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

Hence I created a bootable USB drive and installed Ubuntu 16.04, but now am getting options of memory test as shown in this image [Memory options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIBdP.jpg) when one of the option is chosen which runs the test for 18 hours it passed all the tests that it conducted and no error was found, but there was no end to the test as it was running for continues 18 hours so I exited it.

Can anyone tell me what those options are and how to remove them?

Comment: You don't need to remove it. If you don't want to use MemTest just don't. But it's useful if later you need to diagnose memory. And what you described is typical, the test can run indefinitely but can also be stopped anytime. Also it nothing to do with the Windows error (that has to do with improper installation method).

Answer (score 0):

When running memory tests (or any other for that matter) and no negative results of interest are posted, simply shut off your machine (if there is no elegant method of exiting).

To remove memory tests from the menu (which probably 20% of people do), flag them as non-executable and they won't appear in `grub` menu: [How can I remove memtest from boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608632/how-can-i-remove-memtest-from-boot-menu)

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
sudo update-grub
```