# Update-grub broken, Memtest86+

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I'm using Kubuntu in dual-boot with Windows 10. It was working fine, but yesterday I messed with my kernel and after the long chain of events that ensued where I tried to fix it, I ended up unable to run update-grub, with the following error:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

So the grub menu isn't updated and keeps trying to load a kernel version that I have uninstalled.

Please tell me if any other information is needed.

Edit: I tried to reinstall grub [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows), but after doing

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

I still get the same error message. So, I guess I should make this Memtest86+ available in the EFI partition, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Relevant https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, note that I don't know why it works so if anyone has an explanation feel free to post it:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
sudo update-grub
```

I found it in the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608632/how-can-i-remove-memtest-from-boot-menu) "remove memtest from boot menu". I first uninstalled memtest86+ `sudo apt-get remove memtest86+` as the accepted answer showed, but the issue was still there. I then switched to the other answers and made `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` non-executable.